# Java SecureRandom Instance SHA1PRNG equivalent in Node.JS/

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, cryptography, secure-random

I need to translate a function in Java to Node JS

```
    public byte[] GetId() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
      byte[] byArray = new byte[4];
      byte[] byArray2 = new byte[8];
      SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
      secureRandom.nextBytes(byArray);
      secureRandom.nextBytes(byArray2);
      return byArray2;
    }
```

So what's the equivalence of secureRandom.getInstance and nextBytes to Javascript?

Do I need to use crypto library? like:

```
crypto.randomBytes(8)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [indeed `crypto.randomBytes`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback).  That's the appropriate way to generate cryptographically secure random numbers in Node.JS.

Also note that in Java, you don't really want to explicitly use the `SHA1PRNG` implementation if you can avoid it.  It's much better to use the OS default PRNG if possible, since the `SHA1PRNG` has some known weaknesses, so you'd just write `new SecureRandom()`, which will do the right thing on every platform.